# Change background color of button when Bootstrap 4 collapse element is open

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is it possible to change the background color of a button that opens a collapse card?  My goal is to highlight the button that corresponds to the active data target.

As an example, here is the button that I want to highlight, but only if it's data target (div id january) is opened.  If the data target (div id february) is opened the january button is no longer highlighted and the february button is highlighted. If no data targets are open, no buttons are highlighted.

```
    <!-- January -->

        <div class="card col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
             data-target="#january" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="january">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  January
            </button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-target` represents and html element with `id="january"` which is missing.

But assuming you have it elsewhere 2 things happen when you click the button.

1. `#january`, after the animation completes, will have the class `collapse`
2. the button, after the animation completes, will have the class `collapsed` which you can style

Here I'm using the card header as the collapse "button" and styling via css

#### EDIT: Modified snippet per OP comment

```css
#card1 .card-header {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#card1 .collapsed {
  background-color: red !important;
}

#card2 .card-header {
  background-color: red;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#card2 .card-header.collapsed {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03)
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="card1" class="card">
  <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#january">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div id="january" class="card-body collapse show">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="card2" class="card">
  <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#february">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div id="february" class="card-body collapse show">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that.  Yes, I do have the div id january later on.                    

`<div id="accordionDetail">
    
        <div id="january" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="january" data-parent="#accordionDetail">
            <div class="card-body">
'                                                                                                  
                
When I add that css, the button does change color, but only when the detail div, closes.  It does not change color when it is open.  I was hoping to change it's background color only when the target is open.

Comment: That should just be a matter of reversing the styling for the button based on those states.

Comment: I modified the snippet with a second example